# Change QGIS logo when QGIS 3,8 starts

Tags: qgis

I want to change the QGIS logo(like in the image) when QGIS starts. Can me help someone for this?
[image: Change QGIS Logo]

Comment: Does that work for the 3.8 version of QGIS too? Because in that explanation it seems not to work.

Comment: Check this plugin code : https://github.com/NathanW2/qgis_hats

Comment: @J.Monticolo it tells an error like this: Couldn't load plugin 'qgis_hats' due to an error when calling its initGui() method 
urllib.error.URLError: